# I addded a custom field in mdl_user in SQL, I want to show this custom field in the frontend, in profile edit page

Tags: moodle

I am using Moodle 3.8, I added a custom field called razon_social, I just want to show it in the profile edit page, in the optional section.

[Custom field added in mdl_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJLBt.png)

[Section where I want to show my custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f9MV.png)

Does anyone know in which file in .php, do I have to call my custom field?

Thank you very much for your time

I want to do this, I have Moodle 3.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akXWq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a custom field to the mdl_user table (or any other core table) is a really bad idea. There are all sorts of ways it can conflict with the core code (particularly for tables which Moodle uses with "persistent" classes, but still a problem in other situations).

Thankfully, Moodle already has a build in custom user field system (using the tables mdl_user_info_field and mdl_user_info_data) and fields defined this way automatically appear on the user profile page (unless you mark them as hidden).

It should be fairly easy to write a script that will transfer the data from the mdl_user field you created, into a custom user field. After that, you can drop the extra field you added.

Comment: Nice recommendation, thank you very much and I will take your advice.